# Is it possible to reuse ACFs and change field titles dependant on the page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have 8 pages in a WP installation that need ACFs. The page structure is identical, and so does each of the custom fields. However, the TITLES of each of the custom fields must be different.

I can, of course, make 8 page templates for each of the 8 ACFs, but that is too tedious.

Is it possible for me to have 1 page template for each of the 8 ACFs, and be able to change the title of each field for each page?

Comment: Where are you getting the field titles? Are you hard coding them or pulling them from the acf?

Comment: If you are able to hardcode the eight titles for each field, it should be easy enough to store them in an associative array, object or even constants. Then you could fetch them with a function. If you give me a code sample, I can give you more info.

Comment: Just use a ( more or less elaborated ) `IF` statement by accessing the ACF object .